# Getting 'CG\Proxy\InterceptorLoaderInterface' error with JMS Bundle in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I am trying to install symfony2 JMS DI Extra bundle.
But i keep getting this error

> Fatal error: Interface 'CG\Proxy\InterceptorLoaderInterface' not found
>   in
>   /home/xxxxx/public_html/XXXX/Symfony/vendor/bundles/JMS/AopBundle/Aop/InterceptorLoader.php
>   on line 30

I have found the solution here

https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle/issues/7

But could not able to understand where to fix the path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's cg-library is missing. Open a command prompt into your Symfony vendor folder and issue:

```
git clone https://github.com/schmittjoh/cg-library.git cg-library
```

The add cg-library into your deps file:

```
[cg-library]
    git=https://github.com/schmittjoh/cg-library.git
    target=/cg-library
```

Comment: @Zombie15 you're welcome. Don't forget to mark this as an answer, thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to register CG namespace directory in autoload.php :-)